# Is it possible to bind an Openvswitch bridge with two different interfaces?

Tags: networking, network-programming, openvswitch

I'm starting to "play" with openvswitch and networking staff so I am a little bit newbie. I'm trying to have the following implementation as it depicted in this figure:
[implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDNwt.png)

Both interfaces are physical with a private IP assignement.
*The enO interface is a managament interface

I use this to create the ovs-bridge

```
ovs-vsctl add-br ovsBr
ip add add 192.168.200.1/24 dev ovsBr
```

What should I do next?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an educational task of sorts, then I believe one may not suggest a correct solution without seeing the textual description of the task. However, if you need to create a bridge and add `enp6s0f1` and `enp6s0f2` to it, then you probably want to do the following:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br ovsBr
ovs-vsctl add-port ovsBr enp6s0f1
ovs-vsctl add-port ovsBr enp6s0f2
```